# How to generate customObject cls files in VS Code using SalesforceDX

Tags: custom-object, salesforcedx, vs-code

In my VS Code project there is a folder:

```
tools > sobjects > customObjects
```

Which contains `.cls` file representations of the custom objects.

I've recently run command:

```
SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org
```

And I've got the latest meta data, but I am missing some `.cls` files the folder:

```
tools > sobjects > customObjects
```

Is there a command I need to run to generate these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those files will be refreshed from the org your project is connected to if you open the command palette in vscode and run `SFDX: Refresh SObject Definitions`.